# Javascript function file parameter

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a JS function that gets always the same file as parameter, like this:

```js
function something(../content/id.csv){
  //do something with this file
}
```

Is there a way to do it, without `<file>` input HTML tags?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: So, you want to always use the value for the argument? Or do you want to only call that function if the value is the right one?

Comment: "_I'm trying to write a js function that gets always the same file as parameter_" Then you don't need a parameter, just hard code it inside the function.

Comment: @devius I'd like to use that value for the argument.

Comment: @csmckelvey and how do i do that?

Comment: What HTML tags?

Comment: `var file = "../content/id.csv"`

Comment: A function usually contains code that is used multiple times; it sounds like you're writing a function for the sake of doing it without understanding what the point of having a function is.

Answer (score 2):

- **(Suggestion)** Remove that param and use a local variable within that function.
- But, if you want to call the function as follow `something()` and always will be that way, you can do this:

```js
function something(path = '../content/id.csv'){
  console.log(path);
}

something();
```

## Resource

- [Default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

Comment: Note that the example shows a relatively new feature of ES2015 that isn't supported in all browsers: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-default_function_parameters